# How to use color ramp with torus

Tags: uv, shaders, color

I have a torus and I need the material to use a color ramp so that all the surface has one color (red) except for a strip along the longest edge (yellow). Something like this:

[image]
[image]

I tried unrap in every way with no good results. Also, tried to add seams and nothing. What is the way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Give different material to appropriate faces.If faces along the strip are to big, add some edgeloops.

Comment: If you want to use texture, then follow this [nice tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GP8b5Zg2hI)

Comment: In edit mode U -> Project from view (bounds) from ortho side view (that you have in top picture) and then add a texture colored red at the top and bottom and yellow in the middle (like spanish flag) and have it use the UVs .

Comment: But I don't want a texture, I want a color ramp. Not possible?

Comment: Yes possible, If you want to use internal you can use "blend" type which is a generated gradient. You could even use it with generated coords if you don't need the UV control. And for Cycles there is already an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This type of material is super easy to do in cycles. First break down what you want to do.

1. You want to have a gradient (three color stops).
2. You want the gradient running along the Z axis.

With that as our objective, we don't even need to touch any UV mapping.

Start by getting a gradient running in the direction you want (Z axis).
There are several ways to do this, but I like to simply split the generated texture coordinates, and use the Z component. That *is* the gradient, no other nodes needed.

All that is left to do is run that (think of it as the direction data) in to a color ramp node to colorize it the way you want.

You can do all that with a *Separate XYZ* node plugged in to the *Generated* socket of a *Texture Coordinate* node. Then take the Z output of the Separate XYZ node and plug it in to the color ramp. (Like in the image below)
[image: cycles material nodes]

Comment: Thanks David, that is exactly what I was looking for. What I was missing was the "Separate XYZ"!

Comment: You can change the colour ramp interpolation from linear to constant to get a sharp edge between colours.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the setup for internal renderer:

[image]

UVs were projected from side view. You can also use Generated coordinates by changing the Y (middle dropdown below Projection options) mapping to Z as shown.