# How can I make the texture gradient?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I've modelled an apple and I gave it colors but the top has a stem which seens to start brown and finish green. I tried to replicate that but I don't know how to make the textures smoother (gradient) (starting brown and slowly becoming green)

[image: Left How it is/Right how I would like]
**Left How it is/Right how I would like**

I'm a beginner, sorry if that sounds obvious

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a gradient texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5491/how-do-i-colour-a-3d-terrain-based-on-its-height and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5422/how-to-apply-gradient-color-change-in-an-animation/ also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65378/how-to-use-color-ramp-with-torus/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a gradient texture in the node editor to determine the color. In the node setup in the photo, I am using a gradient texture with generated coordinates. I then rotated it to the correct axis with the mapping node, and also scaled it for a better effect. I then plugged the output of the gradient in a color ramp node, setting black to brown and white to green, giving the color scheme you want. Hope this helps! [image]

Comment: It worked but only when I used the object option in the texture coordinate and also the mapping node wasn't working very well, so I removed it. For now I will just keep as it is since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Glad I could help.